# React Materialize SideNav Close

Tags: javascript, reactjs, materialize

I want to add a close button on react materialize SideNav  I have disabled onclick to false as I do not want it to close on click anywhere except the close button I am not using jquery and working mainly on react.

here is the link to react materializecss 
https://react-materialize.github.io

```
<SideNav
    trigger={<Button>SIDE NAV</Button>}
    options={{ closeOnClick: false}}
    >
```

Comment: And what's your problem exactly?

Comment: I want to add a close button which will close the sideNav    
https://react-materialize.github.io/#/sidenav

Comment: Hmm, not seeing anything in the docs that says they support that kind of functionality. Is there some way to trigger an `onClose` event for the `SideNav`?

Comment: hey, Chase, I tried to trigger a click on another element I still have not yet figured it out yet

Comment: Does anyone found the solution?